# Show res/raw/data.xml in expandablelistview

Tags: android, xml

I tried to make expandableListView data in `res/raw/data.xml` but i don't know how to connect it. Before it, i am using direct data from activity like this:

```
private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Basic");
        listDataHeader.add("Data Types");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("Introduction");
        top250.add("Data Types");
        top250.add("Schema");
        top250.add("Use in Ajax");
        top250.add("Examples");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("Overview");
        nowShowing.add("Array");
        nowShowing.add("Boolean");
        nowShowing.add("Object");
        nowShowing.add("Number");
        nowShowing.add("String");
        nowShowing.add("False");
        nowShowing.add("True");
        nowShowing.add("Null");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);

    }
}
```

I want to add data from `res/raw/data.xml`. here's the `data.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entries>
        <section name="Basics">
            <entry id="1">
                <name>Introduction</name>
                <htmlfilename>basics_intro</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="2">
                <name>Data Types</name>
                <htmlfilename>basics_datatypes</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="3">
                <name>Schema</name>
                <htmlfilename>basics_schema</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="3">
                <name>Use in Ajax</name>
                <htmlfilename>basics_ajaxuse</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="4">
                <name>Cheat Sheet</name>
                <htmlfilename>basics_cheatsheet</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="4">
                <name>Examples</name>
                <htmlfilename>basics_examples</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
        </section>
        <section name="Data Types">
            <entry id="5">
                <name>Overview</name>
                <htmlfilename>datatypes_overview</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="6">
                <name>Array</name>
                <htmlfilename>datatypes_array</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="7">
                <name>Boolean</name>
                <htmlfilename>datatypes_boolean</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="8">
                <name>Object</name>
                <htmlfilename>datatypes_object</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="9">
                <name>Number</name>
                <htmlfilename>datatypes_number</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="10">
                <name>String</name>
                <htmlfilename>datatypes_string</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="11">
                <name>true</name>
                <htmlfilename>datatypes_true</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="11">
                <name>false</name>
                <htmlfilename>datatypes_false</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
            <entry id="11">
                <name>null</name>
                <htmlfilename>datatypes_null</htmlfilename>
            </entry>
        </section>
    </entries>
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are adding data statically in `listDataHeader` and `listDataChild`. to fill data in ArrayList and HashMap from xml file change `prepareListData()` method as:

**1.** Move `data.xml` file in `assets` directory instead of `res`.

**2.** Use `AssetManager` for reading file as `InputStream`  from assets :

> ```
>   AssetManager assetManager = YourAcivityClassName.this.getAssets();
>   InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("data.xml");
> ```

**3.** Parse xml using `SAX` or `DOM` parsers to get all nodes data in ArrayList and HashMap.See following tutorial for pasring xml using `SAXParser` :
 [Android parse XML file from Assets or internal/external storage](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-parse-xml-file-from-assets-or.html)

Comment: @markshadow: you can place more then one file in assets